# How can I see my "Recently Deleted Questions" and "Recently Deleted Answers" on all Stack Exchange websites at once?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-posts-pages

How can I see my [deleted-recent-posts](/questions/tagged/deleted-recent-posts) on all Stack Exchange websites at once?

Answer (score 5):

There's no built-in way to do this; the usual tools (SEDE, the API) fail because they don't contain (enough) information about deleted posts.

One could write a userscript which fetches recently deleted posts from your profile, not unlike @Floern's [Global Flag Summary](https://stackapps.com/q/7173/34061) and my derivation [Global Review Summary](https://stackapps.com/q/7723/34061) which consolidate cross-site activity on your [network profile page](https://stackexchange.com/users/current).